# How to make a List of Generic Objects?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm having trouble with this situation:

I've this generic class:

```
public class InformationsOlv<T> {
    private T _valeur;

    public String Nom { get; private set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I would like to store any objects of InformationsOlv type in a collection.

So I could store it in a List of Objects but I would have to cast every time I want to get information about this object.

So I thought "I should make an abstract class and make InformationsOlv inherit from it"

So I did:

```
public abstract class AInformationsOlv {
    public String Nom;
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
}
```

And changed InformationsOlv like this:

```
public class InformationsOlv<T>:AInformationsOlv {
    private readonly T _valeur;

    ...
}
```

It's not bad, if I make a List of AInformationsOlv objects and store InformationsOlv objects in it. I can access  Nom and TimeStamp variables from it (without cast) but of course I can't access _valeur neither can I put _valeur in AInformationsOlv class, because it would have to become a generic class and then the problem would be the same.

Is there a way I can make something like this in an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AInformationsOlv {
    public String Nom;
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
    protected ? _valeur;
}
```

Where ? means: "Child classes will contain a _valeur class variable, I don't know what type is that variable, child will define it".

Thank you

Comment: Nope, I don't understand a word of that.

Comment: Read it at least twice now. I'm totally not following what your trying to say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding generic object to generic list in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754341/adding-generic-object-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to avoid casting your objects. Pretty sure it's unavoidable in this context.

Comment: I dont' quite get why you need the abstract class. With generics, you'll get what you want: a `InfomationsOlv<int>` would have a `_valeur` of type `int`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand, I'm not english and I explained it the best I could. What I'm trying to do it to store those InformationsOlv objects in a collection and be able to access all their member variables from the collection items, like:
myList[0]._valeur, but _valeur is generic so I can't make it

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer indeed, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: @germi I think the point of the base class is to define a `List<AInformationsOlv>` that could be of various generic types of `InformationsOlv<T>`.

Comment: @DStanley That makes sense. I didn't get that from the question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can define a member  with a type that mans "Children classes will contain a _valeur class variable, I don't know what type is that variable, children will define it".

Sure - use `object` as the type:

```
protected object _valeur;
```

Think about it - if `_valeur` can be of different types - how do you know what type you're dealing with at compile time?  And so how do you *use* it?

---

Take `List<T>` for example - suppose you want a `List<List<?>>`, where the inner list can be of any type.  Right now you can use `List<object>`, you can even use `List<IEnumerable<object>>` to guarantee that the inner lists are at least some form of `IEnumerable<T>`.  But let's suppose your syntax existed:

```
var funkyList = new List<List<?>>();
```

I can now add lists of any type:

```
funkyList.Add(new List<int>());
funkyList.Add(new List<Foo>());
funkyList.Add(new List<Bar>());
```

Now you extract one of the inner `List`s:

```
List<?> l = funkyList[1];
```

But what is `?`?  If you don't know what the type of the list is, how are you going to do anything useful with it?  At best you'd have to use reflection (or `dynamic`) to get the inner type anyways, which negates the power of generics.

Answer (score 0):

If your sub classes are going to define the type of the variable then you have no way of accessing it in base class at compile time. So why bother adding it there?

You have two options, Either don't add it in base class, or define it as `Object`.

```
public abstract class AInformationsOlv 
{
    public String Nom;
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
    protected object _valeur;
}
```