# Can I use generic getter/setter methods on multiple lists of same base types in C#

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, member

I want to know if there is a way I can create generic getter and setter methods for the below code.

Currently the setter checks the actual type of the input object and adds it to the relevant list. It feels like a bad approach to me, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

I can't use any other data structures like a dictionary because I am using a serialisation system that can only serialise simple collection types like Lists and arrays, hence all the individual lists.

```
public abstract class BaseStyleType {}
public class ImageStyle  : BaseStyleType {}
public class TextStyle   : BaseStyleType {}
public class ButtonStyle : BaseStyleType {}
//...etc

public class GlobalStyle : ASerializedObject
{
    public List<ImageStyle>  ImageStyles     = new List<ImageStyle>();
    public List<TextStyle>   TextStyles      = new List<TextStyle>();
    public List<ButtonStyle> ButtonStyles    = new List<ButtonStyle>();
    //... etc

    // Setter
    public void SetStyle(BaseStyleType inStyle)
    { 
        if (inStyle as ImageStyle != null)
            ImageStyles.Add((ImageStyle)inStyle);
        else if (inStyle as TextStyle != null)
            TextStyles.Add((TextStyle)inStyle);
        else if (inStyle as ButtonStyle != null)
            ButtonStyles.Add((ButtonStyle)inStyle);
        //... etc
    }

    // Getter
    public T GetStyle<T>(int index)
    {
        //...?
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you stop using that outdated serialization system that cannot even take a dictionary? I mean, what exactly are you using that it's so bad?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding generic object to generic list in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754341/adding-generic-object-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can't use things for serialization purposes shouldn't prevent you from actually using them.

The advantage to the following solution is you can infinitely create derives classes from BaseStyleType (or other super types) and you'd only have to create the properties to access the dictionary.

```
public abstract class BaseStyleType {}
public class ImageStyle  : BaseStyleType {}
public class TextStyle   : BaseStyleType {}
public class ButtonStyle : BaseStyleType {}

// NOT THREAD SAFE
public class GlobalStyle
{
   // 
   private Dictionary<Type,List<BaseStyleType>> _lists = 
     new Dictionary<Type,List<BaseStyleType>>();

   // Not sure why you'd use Fields here...
   public IEnumerable<ImageStyle> ImageStyles
   {
     get 
     {
       IEnumerable<ImageStyle> result = null;
       List<BaseStyleType> list;
       if (_lists.TryGetValue(typeof(ImageStyle), out list))
       {
         result = list.Cast<ImageStyle>();
       }
       return result;
     }
   }
   //etc
   //public List<ImageStyle>  ImageStyles     = new List<ImageStyle>();
   //public List<TextStyle>   TextStyles      = new List<TextStyle>();
   //public List<ButtonStyle> ButtonStyles    = new List<ButtonStyle>();


   // Setter
   public void SetStyle<T>(T inStyle)
       where T : BaseStyleType
   {
       List<BaseStyleType> list;
       if (_lists.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
       {
         list.Add(inStyle);
       }
       else
       {
           list = new List<BaseStyleType>();
           list.Add(inStyle);
           _lists.Add(typeof(T), list);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways at least:

1) You got a simple, flat herarchy. Make only lists of BaseStyleType. Let covariance and automatic upcasting take care of the details.

2) Modify your code somewhat like that:

```
public abstract class BaseStyleType {}
public class ImageStyle  : BaseStyleType {}
public class TextStyle   : BaseStyleType {}
public class ButtonStyle : BaseStyleType {}
//...etc

public class GlobalStyle <List1Type, List2Type, List3Type, ... > : ASerializedObject
{
    public List<List1Type>  ImageStyles     = new List<List1Type>();
    public List<List2Type>   TextStyles      = new List<List2Type>();
    public List<List3Type> ButtonStyles    = new List<List3Type>();
    //... etc

    // Setter
    public void SetStyle(BaseStyleType inStyle)
    { 
        if (inStyle as ImageStyle != null)
            ImageStyles.Add((ImageStyle)inStyle);
        else if (inStyle as TextStyle != null)
            TextStyles.Add((TextStyle)inStyle);
        else if (inStyle as ButtonStyle != null)
            ButtonStyles.Add((ButtonStyle)inStyle);
        //... etc
    }

    // Getter
    public T GetStyle<T>(int index)
    {
        //...?
    }
}
```

The problem with long type lists is that you end up having to use lines like 
`GlobalStyle <ImageStyle , TextStyle, ButtonStyle>` every **single** time a the type is needed (field types, return types, paramters, etc.). Starting with two generic placeholders, it is usually a good idea to make a type alias.

```
using CustomGlobalStyle = GlobalStyle <ImageStyle, TextStyle, ButtonStyle>;
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile, there's no way in which you've tied your generic constraints to your `BaseStyleType` implementations, so your lists are going to reject the explicitly cast objects as being unable to convert.

Comment: @JonathonChase: I am not aware of any explicit casting anywhere in that code. And I only said "somewhat like that", aknowledging that it was not properly workable code.